# Two questions about CALayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, calayer

- with `[myLayer setName:@"layer_1"]` I set the name of a layer. But how can I get it from another method? Is there something like `[self.view.layer.sublayers getLayerByName:@"layer_1"]`?
- how to animate a `CALayer` to move it to another position with a nice smooth effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `name` property is primarily intended for use by some layout managers, except layout managers don't exist on iOS, so all it's really useful for at this point is debugging.

As for animation, if you're using a CALayer you created yourself, you'll get implicit animations when you change properties. You can set explicit animations using the [CAAnimation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) subclasses, and you can also tweak some parameters of the implicit ones with [CATransaction](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATransaction_class/Introduction/Introduction.html).

If you're using a layer that's associated with a `UIView`, all implicit animations are disabled. You can still create explicit ones with the `CAAnimation` subclasses, or you can use the [UIView animation methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW111).

Comment: For a layer that's associated with a `UIView` you mean `self.view.layer` right? I've created a new layer with `CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer]`. The animation works fine. For getting my layer created in the viewDidLoad method I use an instance variable `CALayer *mylayer`, it's ok? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, a layer pulled from `view.layer` will have implicit animations suppressed. A layer created with `[CALayer layer]` will support implicit animations just fine.